# Marcar un radio button segun el valor de la base de datos

Tags: php, laravel, formularios, radiobutton

En un formulario tengo un ciclo que me genera 3 radiobuttons y le asigna el Id y el nombr que tienen en la base de datos

```
@foreach($type as $t)
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                {{Form::radio('incapacityType',$t->id)}}
                {{Form::label('incapacityType',$t->name)}}
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

Para editar un registro como puedo marcar un radio button segun el valor correspondiente en la base de datos
Ejemplo. Si en el registro se selecciono el 1er radiobutton(value=1) cuando edito ese registro debe seleccionarme ese mismo radio button

Comment: Ese es el mismo archivo blade ke usas para las dos operaciones (crear y editar) ???

Comment: Que sucede te sale deseleccionados todos o ese en particular cuando lo editas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado
valide si el resultado de la base de datos es igual al valor del radio button si es asi lo marca si sigue al siguiente ($t->id == $regiter->regType->id ? true : false)

```
@foreach($type as $t)
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                {{Form::radio('incapacityType',$t->id,$t->id == $absence->absType->id ? true : false)}}
                {{Form::label('incapacityType',$t->name)}}
            </div>
            @endforeach
```